# How add/update data in db with reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, save, iqueryable

I would like to save/update my changes in db with reflection. 
I just have name of a table and the id pk of the field. 
I try to update this table with reflection...

```
 var table =(IQueryable)dbContext.ctx
      .GetType()
      .GetProperty(tableName)
      .GetValue(dbContext.ctx, null);
```

First I have the table and with the Iqueryable I don't know how I can update my table in db.

Any help?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for a completeness of what you should do. Using `Set` (non-generic version) is the right approach. I know you just know the `tableName` (even the `Type` of your entity is not known). But `Set` requires a `Type`. So you need to find that type based on the `PropertyType` of the `PropertyInfo` you obtained from `tableName`. After obtaining a `DbSet` (non-generic), you can use all its methods without any more reflection. The entity passed in will be just `object`. Here is the detailed code:

```
//we don't check if tableName can be resolved successfully for simplicity
//NOTE that there should be only one generic argument
//We know it's a DbSet<T>, with this we should have T
var entityType = dbContext.ctx.GetType().GetProperty(tableName)
                          .PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
//now obtain an instance of DbSet normally
var entities = dbContext.ctx.Set(entityType);
//all methods of DbSet are available now although the arguments are 
//object (not strongly typed).
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need the `DbSet<TEntity>`?

```
var dbSet = (IDbSet<SomeEntity>)dbContext
                   .GetType()
                   .GetProperty(tableName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                   .GetValue(dbContext, null);
```

[Now call `DbSet<TEntity>` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx) as you would do it in a regular scenario, since you've a typed `DbSet<T>`.

A queryable won't help you much because as you've already guessed, it's about querying rather than performing write operations back to the database.

### OP said...

> I can't use DbSet because I never know the entity, I ve juste the
>   name of the table. I make an back office for change value of reference
>   table, an generic interface..

Then, your solution is going with reflection even to add the entities to the `DbSet<TEntity>`:

```
object dbSet = dbContext
                   .GetType()
                   .GetProperty(tableName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                   .GetValue(dbContext, null);

dbSet.GetMethod("Add", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
     .Invoke(new object[] { someEntityTypedAsObject });
```

Or you can store the `DbSet<TEntity>` as a dynamically-typed reference. This way, you can call it without reflection. It's a performance and readability gain:

```
dynamic dbSet = dbContext
                       .GetType()
                       .GetProperty(tableName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                       .GetValue(dbContext, null);

dbSet.Add(someEntity);
```

Comment: I can't use DbSet<t> because I never know the entity, I ve juste the name of the table. I make an back office for change value of reference table, an generic interface..

Comment: @Yvan I've re-updated it. Check the `dynamic` part ;)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `GetProperty` here, because context can contain entity sets, which were created using [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%28System.Type%29)/[`Set<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set%60%601) methods (thus, without any properties declared within context type).

The second, assuming, that entity types are unknown statically, you need to cast the result of non-generic `Set` call to non-generic [`DbSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) type, and call its `Add`/`Remove`/etc methods.